# How to send Http Post request to an external secure https page in Classic ASP?

Tags: https, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest, serverxmlhttp

I can not send http request to an external page starts with **https**. However I used setOption(2) = 13056 to ignore secutrity errors I receive this error:
**msxml3.dll error '80072f8f'
A security error occurred**. I have no access to my server configuration and looking for a programmatic solution.

```
<%
Dim data, httpRequest, postResponse

data= "a="&request.querystring("a")
Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
httpRequest.setOption(2) = 13056
httpRequest.Open "POST", "https://example.com", False
httpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

httpRequest.Send data

postResponse = httpRequest.ResponseText

'Response.Write postResponse ' or do something else with it
%>
```

Comment: Is this solution any help - https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26457879/Cannot-connect-using-https-msxml3-dll-error-'80072f8f'-A-security-error-occurred.html? Have you tried a later version of msxml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by switching from this:

```
Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

to this

```
Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
```